# Is there a way of getting map subsections referenced on main map in qgis?

Tags: qgis, cartography

Is there any way of getting subsections of a map as in, you have a larger map area in which you want to take out 3 smaller areas (A, B and C), you reference them on the "main map"

Currently I have people drawing the A, B and C areas on paint but is there a more direct way of doing it?

Comment: Also you can look at this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163684/creating-main-and-secondary-map-in-qgis

Comment: @ahmadhanb the first is way too vague and not helpful, the 2nd one is a bit better. anyway I found a way better tutorial here https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/automating_map_creation.html