# Creating multiple maps in a QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, raster, print-composer, layouts

I'm relatively new to QGIS - I'm switching from MapInfo.

I'd like to have two separate maps in my print composer in QGIS. One the main frame linked to my canvas window and the other a raster image from OS mapping (an overview of the project). Screenshots attached of my current QGIS window and the MapInfo layout I'm trying to replicate.

I can't work out how to just bring my raster into the small map window at the moment. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: probable duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80182/adding-multiple-maps-in-qgis-composer?rq=1

Comment: Each map has their own scale and position back to the main map, and the pan/zoom tool for the map will work separately for each map. I think it's just going to be a matter of learning to use the navigation tools and setting scale/extent for each map... tricky at first...

Answer (score 1):

If you want your main map and overview map to have two separate sets of visible layers, I would recommend using Map Themes ([see official documentation here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#map-themes)) and setting up two themes, one for your main map and one for the overview. This is a superior option, IMO, to the 'lock layers' option suggested in the answer to the linked question in the comments, as you can have any number of themes and switch between them any time, and update the theme as required (which then updates any maps using that theme).

You also need to change the scale of your overview map and center it appropriately. Use the Set to map canvas extent button (it's just above 'Main properties' in your second screenshot, on the right) and the [Move item content tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_map.html#extents) to move around and scale your map content in the overview map.